# Migrating from svn to github enterprise without loosing commit history

Tags: github, svn, git-svn

We were using SVN for quite a long time in our office and now recently it is decided that we should move to GitHub enterprise and all source code should be maintained there. Our current SVN server is an on premises windows 2012 R2 server in our private network. We are already maintaining new project on GitHub enterprise but these are few project for which we cannot take risk of loosing our commit history and branches tags etc. For migrating a quick google search brings

`git svn clone <svn-repository-url>`

but this is not possible as our SVN server is behind a corporate firewall and there is no change that network and Infosec guys will allow the server to available on public internet. Is there any other way by which we migrate all our project to GitHub. Something like export SVN repo as .zip or .tar and then upload it to GitHub or any other possible solution would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have shell access to the server you can run `svnadmin dump` on each of your repos. It works on windows too, not just linux. This is thouroughly explained in the svn book. It is not difficult to do but as usual there are many options and possibilities.

When converting to git, I would recommend getting rid of meaningless branches, but that's up to you of course.